# Does setting DEADLOCK_PRIORITY to LOW cause a stored procedure to run slower?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, stored-procedures, deadlock

I have a Stored Procedure that I have written that deletes rows from a table in the database.  When I will run the Stored Procedure in the Production environment it will run whilst another program is inserting rows into the same table.  In case there is a deadlock I want my Stored Procedure to be the one that is killed.

In the Stored Procedure I have set DEADLOCK_PRIORITY to LOW.

When doing testing in my test environment I am finding that having this option set it makes the deletion run a lot slower.  In the testing environment the process that inserts records is not running so, in theory, there is no locking issue.

I am finding that when the DEADLOCK_PRIORITY is set to LOW it is taking 1.5 hours to delete ~500,000 rows.  When the DEADLOCK_PRIORITY is not set (ie using the default setting) the deletion of the rows only takes around 15 minutes.

Is there a reason why there is such a difference?

The database is using Simple Recovery model in the test environment.  (In the Production environment it is using the FULL recovery model).

Thanks.

Comment: Recovery model is irrelevant here as DELETE is always fully logged. You should check yor WAITS while execute your delete in both cases (see sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to guess here... transaction log file sizes

In the test system was small and grew when you tested the first time with LOW
When you re-run without LOW, then log file was already sized correctly.

Easy to verify: check the "lastwaittype" in sys.sysprocesses (deprecated but useful) to see if you gave LOG related waits affecting the SPID doing the DELETE.

Otherwise double check that the 2 executions are identical

- same data
- any triggers enabled
- ditto foreign keys, indexes
- foreign key cascades
- ...

Also see [Why does an UPDATE take much longer than a SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009659/why-does-an-update-take-much-longer-than-a-select/2009693#2009693)